# Should chunks of fiberglass looking material be present in my bypass humidifier?

Tags: hvac, fiberglass

See the attached photo. It's only really visible on the top here, but this fiberglass looking material (duct liner?) is present on all four sides.

Should I remove this material, or otherwise work to seal it off (maybe with HVAC tape) from the airflow?

Edit: In other words, should the bypass humidifier have been mounted on the inner metal? (see that piece of yellow metal near the top). I have attached more photos to try to make it more obvious what is happening here.

Final edit: My heat exchanger (I think that's the name) has an inner sheet of metal, them that fiberglass looking lining, followed by another sheet of metal. In the first photo, the inner sheet of metal is visible inside the bypass humidifier - colored yellow. The outer metal is green (and the people who installed this screwed a sheet of metal on top of that, which is silver).

So: should the bypass humidifier be connected to the outer sheet of metal, or the inner one? As a lay person, it seems to me that being connected to the outer sheet of metal means conditioned air is necessarily blowing into the space between the two sheets of metal, which has that lining in it.

(Also: based on the shape of cuts on the inner piece of metal, it seems clear to me that the previous bypass humidifier was directly connected to the inner sheet, not the outer sheet.)

[image: fiberglass looking stuff]

[image: better view of inner metal]

[image: view of inner metal and insulation, looking down]

[image: side view of metal]

Comment: It might be there to stop the cold/warmth of the heat exchanger from being transmitted directly to the duct.   You want to condition the air, not the metal duct work.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be insulation that is built into the unit.  I don't see any "chunks" that are obviously where they should not be.

Comment: Yes, that's right - I think it's part of the heat exchanger lining. I guess what I'm really asking is: should that open space between the heat exchanger and the humidifier exist? As it is, it lets conditioned air blow into the space with the lining, not just through the humidifier.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the bypass humidifier should have been installed on the inner wall (seemingly made of compressed fiberglass) rather than the exterior metal wall.

Installing the humidifier on the exterior metal wall allowed conditioned air to be blown into the space between the inner fiberglass wall and the outer metal wall.

This lead to mold growth on the (silver backed) fiberglass liner between the two walls.